# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2+2x+4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Using residue calculus, I have no idea how to find the poles of $x^2+2x+4$.

Comment: To find the poles of this function $f(z):= \frac{\cos z}{z^2 + 2z + 4}$, you need to find the **roots** of $z^2 + 2z+4$ and their multiplicities (and also the roots of $\cos z$).

Comment: There's a **formula** for finding the roots of a **quadratic** function.  I wish I remembered what it was called....

Comment: After you do this, construct a contour consisting of an upper semicircular arc of radius $R$ and line segment $[-R,R]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{cos x}{x^2+2x+4}dx&=\int^\infty_{-\infty}Re\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2z+4}\right)dz\\
&=Re\left(\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int^R_{-R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2z+4}dz\right)\\
(Residue formula)\quad&=Re\left(2\pi iRes\left[\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2z+4},-1+\sqrt{3}i\right]-\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Gamma_R}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2z+4}\right)dz\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $D_R$ be the half-disk in the upper half-plane bounded by the interval $[-R,R]$ on the real axis and the semicircular contour $\Gamma_R$ of radius $R$.

Note that $-1+\sqrt{3}i$ is a simple zero in $D_R$. By formula,
$$
Res\left[\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2z+4},-1+\sqrt{3}i\right]=\frac{e^{iz}}{2z+2}\Big|_{-1+\sqrt{3}i}=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}-i}}{2\sqrt{3}i}
$$
On the other hand, since $|e^{iz}|\leq 1$ in the upper half-plane, then
$$
\left\vert\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2z+4}dz\right\vert\leq\frac{1}{R^2-2R-4}\cdot\pi R\rightarrow 0
$$
as $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Thus,
$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{cos x}{x^2+2x+4}dx=Re\left(\frac{\pi e^{-\sqrt{3}-i}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{\pi e^{-\sqrt{3}cos(-1)}}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $x^2+2x+4=(x+1)^2+3$, so $x+1=\pm\sqrt{3}i$. (If you really don't remember the general formula).